# Pressing ctrl on Remix takes me to the variable/funcion declaration. How to disable it?

Tags: remix

A simple Remix shortcut is driving me crazy. Whenever I press ctrl, it takes me to another region on the code (or another file) where the variable/function at the cursor position was declared, because of this, I can't really copy-paste variable names, or "skip" to the end/stard of words using ctrl, or multi-select with crtl+D, or pretty much anything that involves the ctrl key. This just started recently, I've been using remix for a couple of years without having this problem. Any ideas of what could be happening?

ps: I'm on chrome/windows if this makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after solving the problem:

Apparently, a chrome extension was interfering with the editor, disabling extension access on the Remix IDE website solved the issue.